# Can you swim underwater?

Tags: satisfactory

I've been struggling to understand how swimming underwater in this game works.  Usually, most games use the same button as the crouch key to dive down, and the jump button to ascend.  So far, the only way I can figure out how to dive down is by jumping into water and letting the momentum of my jump bring me down.  The problem with this is it's not always possible to get a big enough jump to make a difference, and eventually you float back up to the surface (not to mention it's a weird way to descend underwater in general).

Pressing the crouch key appears to make my characters head go underwater, but I can't dive any further after that.  The jump key (<kbd>space</kbd>) *does* allow you to ascend.  Nothing in the game controls seem to map to swimming specific controls either.

There are underwater caves that I've been able to find and can't explore because of this.  There are also some deep holes with items in them in some lakes.  This makes me think that diving is certainly a feature in the game, but it doesn't seem to exist...

Is it possible to swim underwater with control in Satisfactory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Diving isn't currently a game mechanic in Satisfactory, but there are ways you can get underwater:**

- *Use height + momentum*: Fly up high with the jetpack, then let yourself fall down. Your momentum will enable you to get deeper into the water. Alternatively, jump fro a high cliff or stack of foundations.
- *Use block geometry*: For example, build ramps/foundations to force your character down into the water, or to force your character to stay at a certain depth.

Here are some posts on the Satisfactory Q&A site that reference diving as a feature request as recently as 4 months ago:

- https://questions.satisfactorygame.com/post/5e5b37d2c672159e0cdf87dc
- https://questions.satisfactorygame.com/post/5e5c4caac672159e0cdf8b02
- https://questions.satisfactorygame.com/post/5e4678d6a88e031cdf962cd5

Comment: Building a foundation diving board worked perfectly for me.